# XSLT Converting Unicode characters to visual characters

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT and i have a problem that after applying XSLT style sheet on XML contains unicodes like `&#x03B2;`, converted to `β` in the output XML. what i need is to prevent XSLT style sheet from converting Unicodes to Visual characters.

Any help i will be grateful.
Thanks,

Comment: This is the wrong question; XSLT does not do this. Check your [`output`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output) settings.

Answer (score 3):

The object model used by XPath, unlike DOM, considers all entities and CDATA sections resolved. That means that XPath reads the `&#x03B2;` that you are seeing in your source document as the character `β`. So XLST is not really converting anything. It is just reading and outputting the value selected by XPath.

But you *can* use XSLT to represent the `β` as a character entity in the result document. You can select that behaviour by declaring a non-UTF `encoding` in `<xsl:output>` such as "US-ASCII" or "ISO-8859-1".

Suppose you have this source:

```
<character>&#x03B2;</character>
```

Using this stylesheet with `<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" />`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" />
    <xsl:template match="character">
        <result><xsl:value-of select="."/></result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You may get, depending on the implementation of your processor

```
<result>&#946;</result>
```

or

```
<result>&#x3b2;</result>
```

Both represent the same character.

I am not sure, but I think that behaviour is default in XSLT 1.0 processors if you use `xsl:output` with the `method="html"` attribute.